# fun in Z3 returning more than one element

Tags: z3, z3py, theorem-proving

As far as I can see, I can declare a function that returns more than one element. lets say I have a function x which receives a sort T and returns a sort U and a Sort R

(declare-sort T)
(declare-sort R)
(declare-sort U)

(declare-fun x (T) (U R))

how can I access then, when invoking the function x the returning elements ....lets say I need to assert pass U to one function and R to a different one.. can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not well formed SMT-LIB2. It does not parse.
(error "line 3 column 23: invalid number of parameters to sort constructor")
http://www.smtlib.org describes in depth the SMT-LIB2 syntax and semantics.

Comment: Thnak you Nikolaj!! I know is not well formed, I apologize for that I should mention is just pseudo code for trying to explain what I want to do. What I am trying to say is that if having a function x which receives T and returns (U R)  theres is any way of catching the result of invoking x (aka (U R)) and then using them by separate, did I made my point??

Comment: You could define a datatype that holds multiple objects, e.g., along the lines of the definition of Pair in the Z3 Guide on datatypes (http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide)